# ServiceNow integration with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, servicenow, elastic-stack

We are using ELK to monitor the system performance and our application logs. If there is an error in the logs, we want to create an issue in ServiceNow from ELK. Is there a way to do this? Any pointers would help.

Comment: We have the same requirements, did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ELK specifically, but perhaps you could make a SOAP/REST call to do it? 
Just make sure your ELK service account has sufficient permissions, and get the WSDL by going to http://yourinstance.service-now.com/tablename.do?WSDL